# VBA Compile error: Expected end of statement While creating Com Object

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to create an object of a class but vba is throwing syntax error

```
Private Sub cmd_run_Click()
 'process ocr on table
  Dim OCRz As Tesseract

  Set OCRz = New Tesseract

  OCRz.Init("C:\\Users\\aftab\\Downloads\\ocr\\ocr\\tesseract\\tessdata", "eng", OcrEngineMode.OcrEngineMode_TesseractOnly)

  MsgBox "processing"

 'display results
  Me.Requery
End Sub
```

[image: Eror being shown on red]

Comment: Probably just `Set OCRz = New Tesseract` and then `OCRz.Something("C:\\Users\\aftab\\Downloads\\ocr\\ocr\\tesseract\\tessdata", "eng", OcrEngineMode.OcrEngineMode_TesseractOnly)`, i don't know the command you should use to replace `Something`, I didn't saw the doc for VBA on Tesseract...

Comment: I have this method OCRz.Init("C:\\Users\\aftab\\Downloads\\ocr\\ocr\\tesseract\\tessdata", "eng", OcrEngineMode.OcrEngineMode_TesseractOnly) which accepts three parameters but now compile error is changed asking for = sign

Comment: I don't have the doc like I said, but this method probably return something and if not, just get rid of the parenthesis and add a space between `init` and the parameters

Comment: @GSerg : You know  everything!^^ Or do you happened to find the doc in the Tesseract wiki?

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
OCRz.Init "C:\\Users\\aftab\\Downloads\\ocr\\ocr\\tesseract\\tessdata", "eng", OcrEngineMode.OcrEngineMode_TesseractOnly
```

or:

```
Dim Result As Variant
Result = OCRz.Init("C:\\Users\\aftab\\Downloads\\ocr\\ocr\\tesseract\\tessdata", "eng", OcrEngineMode.OcrEngineMode_TesseractOnly)
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a `Call`

```
Call OCRz.Init("C:\\Users\\aftab\\Downloads\\ocr\\ocr\\tesseract\\tessdata", "eng", OcrEngineMode.OcrEngineMode_TesseractOnly)
```

And your error should be gone

It's explained in the [MSDN Call Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251710.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself after trying for several hours, unfortunately I have had to learn the hard way.

First i need to generate a COM by setting C# project properties i.e.

1. Application => Assembly Information => need to check Make assembly COM-Visible
2. Build => under Output => Need to check Register for Comp Interop

Secondly i do need to register my dll generated for Tesseract by following this

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\regasm.exe C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Emgu.CV.OCR.dll /codebase /tlb:C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Emgu.CV.OCR.tlb

Now in the excel i need to instantiate the tesseract object as following

```
Private Sub cmd_run_Click()
   'process ocr on table
    Dim OCRz As New Tesseract("C:\\Users\\aftab\\Downloads\\ocr\\ocr\\tesseract\\tessdata", "eng", OcrEngineMode.OcrEngineMode_TesseractOnly)

    MsgBox "processing"

   'display results
    Me.Requery
End Sub
```

I don't know but the trick was to declare and instantiate the Tesseract object at same point.